# Planck's quantum theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, discrete

Recently came across Planck's theory, $E = h\nu$.

It means that at any frequency, there is given energy. But I also saw that, $E$ can be $0, h\nu, 2h\nu, 3h\nu,...$.

How is it possible that energy can be varied at any given frequency. At at given frequency, there should be certain energy only.
And can $E$ also be $-h\nu, -2h\nu, -3h\nu,...$?

Comment: E cannot be 0 because it would be frequency is 0 thus absolute rest but everything vibrates. And E cannot be negative because vibrations which means frequency is never negative. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have $E_1 = h \nu$, i.e. a photon with frequency $\nu$ has a certain energy $E_1$.

From here, $E_2 = 2 h \nu$ would mean either two photons with frequency $\nu$ (and therefore having twice the total energy, $E_2 = 2 E_1$), or a single photon with twice the frequency $E_2 = h (2\nu)$.

The same goes for your other expressions.

Comment: You shouldn't interpret $2h\nu$ as ```single photon with twice the frequency```. This changed the frequency, effectively changed color of the radiation. It equivalents to  change the amplitude, not the frequency.

Comment: @ytlu I do not understand - changing the color of the radiation is changing the frequency. Changing the amplitude only makes it brighter.

Comment: The $n$-photon number state means brighter. It doesn't imply  the state is changed from red to violet. @Allure

Comment: @ytlu the question doesn't refer to states, though.

Comment: Your answer is ridiculous., Very probaly, the OP is a points collection device.

Answer (score 0):

This is the concept of photon, a quantized energy of radiation. In the wave theory, the energy density $u$ of a radiation is proportional to amplitude $\vec E$:
$$  u = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 E^2 $$
which is a function of the continuous amplitude $E$.

The quantized radiation is called a photon, which limit the energy content of a radiation (of frequency $\nu$) have to be integer multiplicity of the basic unit $h\nu$. Different frequencies have different basic units.

Plank used the concept of photon to derive the average photon number $\bar n (\nu)$ as the function of frequency, knowing as the Plank distribution function. Which then successfully explained the spectrum of black-body radiation in both low and high frequency regions.

Also, the photo-electron experiment, which observed the minimum negative voltage to completely stop the current induced by the photo-electron, confirms that the minimum energy transmitted to electron is $h\nu$. To stop the photo-current from a violet light is much higher than that from a red light.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency is restricted, it's a characteristic of quantum mechanics, I will use infinite potential well as an illustration.

Given a potential: $$V(x)=0\;\; x\in[0,L]\;\;else\;\;V(x)=\infty$$
obviously it has boundary condition:$$\partial \Omega:\psi(0)=\psi(L)=0$$
then solving the Schrodinger equation in the effective range gives $$-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\ddot{\psi}(x)=E\psi(x)$$
this is a a simple differential equation with answer:
$$\psi(x)=Ae^{i\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^{2}}}x}+Be^{-i\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^{2}}}x}$$
the boundary condition of $$\psi(0)=0$$ sets $$A=-B$$
then using euler equation:$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
we can rewrite the expression as:$$\psi(x)=C\sin(\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^{2}}}x)$$
now insert the second boundary condition of $$\psi(L)=0$$
then the wave vector is constrained to:$$kL=\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^{2}}}L=n\pi\;\;\;\; n\in \mathbf{Z}$$
as the wave vector is quantized under the restriction:$$k=\frac{n\pi}{L}\;\;\;\; n\in \mathbf{Z}$$ note $$n \geq 1$$ so energy is restricted to be positive, now using
a heuristic understanding using Debroglie wavelength:$$p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$ then:$$E=hf=h\frac{c}{\lambda}=(\frac{h}{2\pi})ck=\hbar\omega$$
as $$k$$ we shown is restricted so the frequency is also restricted. A remark that you may omit is the actual energy expression in this calculation is $$E=\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{2mL^{2}}$$, nonetheless frequency is also restricted for a more accurate calculation.

Notice this argument is not strictly correct as blackbody radiation calculation requires the quantum field theory, which treat the photon field as a set of simple harmonic oscillator, the calculation result is similar, but much tedious.

So I constrain the reply using only non-relativistic mechanics as an illustration of how quantum mechanics restricted selected frequencies.